# Docker-compose isolate networks by project name

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to do a zero downtime deploying w/ docker-compose and traefik, but I'm having issues with a container cross communicating with another project.

docker-compose.yml (details omitted)

```
services:
   proxy:
      networks:
         - net
   app:
      networks:
         - net
   auth:
      networks:
         - net

networks:
  net:
    external:
       name: traefik_webgateway # not really important here
```

I run two different instances of my services via:

```
docker-compose --env-file=.env --project-name=green -f docker-compose.yml up
docker-compose --env-file=.env --project-name=blue -f docker-compose.yml up
```

My services in "green" work fine until I run the "blue" project. When "blue" is being brought up, some of the requests in the "green" "proxy" container is being routed to the "blue" container. Example call being made in "proxy" to talk to the "auth" service:

```
http://auth/session
```

I need the networking in "green" to stay in "green", and "blue" in "blue"... otherwise some of the requests in "green" is going to "blue" when it isn't ready it causing API failures. Once all the containers are ready, everything works but this isn't zero downtime.

It looks like everything is bound by the container name. I don't want to use `container_name` because I want to use the `docker scale`.

My workaround is creating `docker-compose.blue.yml` and `docker-compose.green.yml` and duplicates everything but suffix the `container name` with `_blue` and `_green`. But I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The proposed solution answers the question, but by adding the `internal` network to my `proxy`, traefik loses communication with my service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `docker-compose` will setup a single, isolated network for your project. When using custom networks those, too, will be namespaced with the project name, isolating projects with different names - see the [`docker-compose` networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

BUT: in your example all the containers are connected to an external network which is not namespaced and thus is the same even for different projects.
Since the container also share the same name resolving them in that network may result in either the *green* or *blue* version.

There are several ways to solve this. The appropriate method depends on your particular use case. The best and also the safest method would be to isolate all containers with the same project name to their own internal network and only expose the ports intended for outside connection into the external network:

```yaml
services:
   proxy:
      networks:
         - net
         - internal
   app:
      networks:
         - internal
   auth:
      networks:
         - internal

networks:
  internal:
  net:
    external:
       name: traefik_webgateway # not really important here
```

Here, all the containers are only connected to a project-scoped, internal network and are able to communicate with each other. Only the `proxy` service is also connected to the external `net` network and can be connected to from there.

If you really need to connect all services to the same external network, you could use [`aliases`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#aliases) together with [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

```yaml
services:
   proxy:
      networks:
         net:
           aliases:
             - proxy_${COLOR}
   app:
      networks:
         net:
           aliases:
             - app_${COLOR}
   auth:
      networks:
         net:
           aliases:
             - auth_${COLOR}

networks:
  net:
    external:
       name: traefik_webgateway # not really important here
```

This is basically your workaround but with a single `docker-compose.yml` which you can use like this:

```sh
COLOR=green docker-compose --env-file=.env --project-name=green -f docker-compose.yml up
COLOR=blue docker-compose --env-file=.env --project-name=blue -f docker-compose.yml up
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! That make sense now :)